# C# SendMessage Without knowing TextBox ID

Tags: c#, external, sendmessage, sendkeys

I'm trying to send a string to an external program, but I only have a sample program of what I will be working with, so I do not know what the actual textBox IDs will end up being.  Obviously this is quite problematic.

What the program does, is allow the user to click a button, which will paste the text onto an external program.  This all works fine using SendKeys. I was then asked to create hotkeys that would allow a person to do a keystroke and it would be the equivalent of pressing a button.

I have hotkeys down, however, when a person uses a hotkey, it ends up sending the message several times.  I've narrowed it down to being the sendKeys function, and I've tried using SendMessage, but I won't know the textBox ID, so from what I can tell, it's not a viable option.  Here is what I have with the SendKeys code.

```
private void FocusProcess(string procName, string message, bool hotkeyed) {
    Process[] objProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName);
    if (autoPasteOn.Checked || toFrontOn.Checked) {
        foreach (Process currentProc in objProcesses) {
            IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
            hWnd = currentProc.MainWindowHandle;
            ShowWindowAsync(new HandleRef(null, hWnd), SW_RESTORE);

            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

            if (autoPasteOn.Checked) {
                SendKeys.Send(message);
            }

            if (toFrontOff.Checked) {
                SetForegroundWindow(mainProg);
                SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works by pulling the other process to the front, sending the message, and then sending it to the back.  I'm registering hotkeys using the SetWindowsHookEx library, and it works fine.  The only problem is sending the message using a hotkey. It works, but it does it a ton of times.  I've placed checks to make it paste at a maximum of 4 times/sec. But it does it around 10-20 times/sec.  I've varified that the code is only executed once every quarter second, but the sendkeys is still messing up.